# should we I use SQL or NoSQL for react-native app

Tags: sql, sqlite, react-native, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm making an react-native app that track drivers. The data from tracking plugin is produced as SQLite. Should we I use SQL or NoSQL?

If go towards NoSQL: 
I'm using AWS and I like dynamo because I don't need to deal w/ serves but I heard that writes are quite expensive. Would it be expensive w/ this type of data?

Or Should I use mongoDB?

[image: Data Schema First draft]

Comment: If your main concern to select SQL or NoSQL is the cost, you are at the wrong site. If, on the other hand, the selection is to be based on technical aspects only, you need to look at your data, see if it shows TABLE-BASED structure and, if yes, use SQL. Otherwise, you can go for NoSQL.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/